# Where do these Paths intersect

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

We have two paths:

$r(t)=\langle cos(t),0,sin(t)\rangle $

$s(t)= \langle 0,cos(t),sin(t)\rangle$

where $t$ in $[0,pi]$

We are given that they are on the surface of $F(x,y,z)= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -1$

Show that the intersection of these two paths occurs at $\langle0,0,1\rangle$.

My own work showed me:

$cos(t1) = 0$

$0= cos(t2)$

$sin(t1) = sin(t2)$

is true for any $t$. I think I may not be understanding something. Can someone help me see how to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: $\cos t_1 = 0$ and $\cos t_2 = 0$ are NOT true for all $t_1,t_2 \in [0,\pi]$. But those two equalities do hold for some specific choice of $t_1, t_2 \in [0,\pi]$.

Comment: But if so, it is definitely not true for cos(0) as that is 1. So how can they have intersected at such a point?

Comment: $x = 0$ and $t = 0$ are not the same thing.

Comment: OH! so the result of cos(t) = 0. And therefore t = pi/2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the x coordinate of each path, you know that the two paths can intersect only if $\cos(t) = 0$.  The y coordinate reveals the same restriction.  The z coordinate is the same in both paths, so they will be the same no matter what $t$ is used.  Therefore, all you need for the coordinates to intersect is to have $\cos(t) = 0$.

Comment: I have to show that they intersect at (0,0,1) but cos(0) != 0

Comment: true.  and $\sin(t) != 1$.  The point you are looking for does not happen at $t=0$.

Comment: I was confused because I thought that they intersected at a point (0,0,1) mean that t was (0,0,1).